# How to handle a MySQL query when it returns null on await?

Tags: javascript, mysql, async-await

I have an async function with multiple MySQL queries like this:

```
const memberdata = async function() {
 somequery1 = await doquery('id','table1','member_id',userid);
 somequery2 = await doquery('id','table2','member_id',userid);
 somequery3 = await doquery('id','table3','member_id',userid);
 problem = await doquery('id','sessions','member_id',userid);

 const array = {somequery1 : somequery1[0].id, somequery2 : somequery2[0].id, somequery3 : somequery3[0].id, problem : problem[0].id};
 return (array);
   };
   
   memberdata().then(v => {  
    username = v.somequery1;
    sex      = v.somequery2;
    age      = v.somequery3;
    session  = v.problem
});
```

Most of the queries are expected to return a value because there is always at least one record on their tables. The only exception is `problem` where 50% of the time no record will be found thus upon declaring `session` I will get an error saying `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()`.

That wouldn't be a problem if that was the only query but that's not the case so what can I do to have `problem` simply return 0 or null in case no record is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `doquery` always returns a Promise that resolves to an array, you need to check that the array is populated before accessing properties of the `[0]`th element.

When returning, change

```
problem : problem[0].id};
```

to

```
problem : problem.length ? problem[0].id : 0};
```

You also might consider using `Promise.all` to make the code run in parallel.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include on my code. Since I only expect each query to return the first record found I should have declared problem like this: `problem : problem[0].id` because otherwise it would return an object but then I get the same warning if I use your first approach. Why is that?

Comment: That's quite a different issue from what your original code showed. Check that the array has stuff in it before trying to access deeply nested properties, or you'll get errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to learn how if statements work.

My guess is that `doQuery` returns 0 or more records, and your code misbehaves if it's 0, because you are referring to:

```
problem[0].id
```

If the array has 0 elements, this triggers your error.

So the solution is to add an if statement that handles this case:

```
if (problem.length === 0) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do the normal thing
}
```

Comment: sorry but it wont work.

Comment: @CainNuke share what you tried

Comment: I tried `session = v.problem.lenght != 0 ? v.problem[0].id : 0;` but still get the warning.

Comment: Well there's a typo in there at the very least. But if that wasn't it, you should try to share a more complete example.

Comment: its solved now, thank you anyway.

Comment: @CainNuke i see you solved it with a ternary statement, this would have had the same effect.